# Pandas index operations in Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, data-science, pyspark-pandas

In our Data Science project we are playing around pandas dataframe, numpy and scipy libraries and we want to change the code into Pyspark, We are facing issues like:

**wst = cur_buck[:, [0]]**

**cur_buck[:, :-1] = cur_buck[:, 1:] - wst**

**cur_buck[:, -1] = cur_buck[:, -2]**

number_of_particles=100

**particles_matrix[10] = cur_buck[:, -1].reshape(number_of_particles).copy()**

**Same thing how can we achieve in Pyspark?**

Any leads would be highly appreciable like these 4 lines I want to convert in pyspark.

Thanks in advance

Comment: pyspark is distributed processing framework, and distributed processing can't be index based as multiple workers have pieces of the data and are executing the process on their individual pieces simultaneously.

Comment: thats correct, but is there any way to achieve same thing into Pyspark, not exactly with index but something similar to this

Comment: the first line doesn't work on my sample data and throws an error. could you please check the code and share a sample of the input data if the code is okay?

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider moving pyspark data into numpy using the below?:

```
arrayed=np.array(df.select('col1',"col2").collect())
```

You can then perform your calculations on this array and append it back in dataframe but remember you will need a row number column (equivalent of index in pandas) before you do all of this.